# How to get the WebStorage usage/quota for an Android webview?

Tags: android, webview, web-storage

I want to get the usage (in bytes) used by an Android Webview.

I did get through http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebStorage.html but the documentation is not very clear for me.

Any clue on how which origins should I use ?

for now I'm stuck here :

```
    WebStorage
            .getInstance()
            .getOrigins(
                    new ValueCallback<Map>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onReceiveValue(Map webStorageOrigins) {
                                                //WebStorage.getInstance().getUsageForOrigin();
                                                // What now with : webStorageOrigins;

                                            }
                                        }
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found It !
thanks to somebody at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24180

```
            WebStorage.getInstance().getOrigins(new ValueCallback<Map> () {
                @Override
                public void onReceiveValue(Map map) {
                    for(Object key : map.keySet()) {
                        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
                            WebStorage.Origin origin = (WebStorage.Origin) map.get(key);
                            Log.e("AppCache", String.format("Origin: %s Quota: %s Usage: %s",
                                    origin.getOrigin(), origin.getQuota(), origin.getUsage()));
                        } else {
                            Log.e("AppCache", "Key: " + key + " Value: " + map.get(key));
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

I was having hard time to iterate on the Map.

Other way to do it when you have the origin string

```
    WebStorage.getInstance().getUsageForOrigin(TheUrl, new ValueCallback<Long>() {
        @Override
            public void onReceiveValue(Long usage) {
            Log.e("AppCache", "Usage:onReceiveValue: "+ usage);
        }
    });
```